# JS Find an object in an array by one of its properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, arr

Need to find an object by Sarah owner

```
const dogs = [
  { weight: 22, curFood: 250, owners: ['Alice', 'Bob'] },
  { weight: 8, curFood: 200, owners: ['Matilda'] },
  { weight: 13, curFood: 275, owners: ['Sarah', 'John'] }, //need to find this string by name 
  { weight: 32, curFood: 340, owners: ['Michael'] },
];

const findeOwner = dogs.find(acc => acc.owners === 'Sarah');
```

just doesnt work If I remove the square brackets, then the method will work, but this is against the rules. Would you help me?

Comment: The square brackets mean that the value is an `Array`. So you should not compare an array with a string. You can use [`Array.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Comment: To what "rules" are you referring?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`find()`](https://%5B%60Array.find()%60%5D(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)) method to find the object in the array that has "Sarah" as an owner using [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) or [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

```
const dog = dogs.find(dog => dog.owners.includes('Sarah')); //  dog.owners.indexOf('Sarah')>-1
console.log(dog);
```

*Result:*

```
{ weight: 13, curFood: 275, owners: ['Sarah', 'John'] }
```